# How to identify disk make and model attached to a MegaRAID controller?

Tags: hard-drive, lsi, megaraid

I have a system with a LSI MegaRAID SAS 9271-4i and some attached disks in a RAID 10 configuration.  I don't have physical access to the system but I have root access via SSH.

Various tools - lspci, lshw, lsscsi, smartctl - are only able to show me information about the controller, not the disks themselves.

The MegaRAID tool, megacli, will show me various information (including the WWN) about the disks but not the make and model.

It seems like the WWN encodes some information.  For example, as far as I can tell, 5000c500a2xxxxxx belongs to a Seagate drive (000c50 seems to be assigned to Seagate).

Can I get more information out of the system or out of the WWN to determine the make and model of these disks?

Comment: Which commands exactly did you try with `megacli`?

Comment: Mostly `megacli -PDList -aALL` but also `megacli -AdpAllInfo -aALL` and `megacli -pdInfo -PhysDrv [4:0] -aALL`

Comment: You don't have something like `Vendor Id : TOSHIBA 
 Product Id : AL13SXB300N ` in the output of `megacli -ShowSummary -aALL`?

Comment: Yes!  That seems to be the trick.

Comment: Ah alright, I thought you tried that, too.